# Using awk to extract part of string in parentheses

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I know there are couple of question on similar topics but none of them works for me. Specifically, I have:
`the date is (Dec 2013).` as a field in record and I just want the `Dec 2013` part and store it in a variable. I tried `match()` but it does not work. Here is my code (the field is $2):

```
match($2,/\(([^)]+)\)/,a);
print a[0];
```

But it gives me an error `awk: illegal statement at source line 8 source file script.awk`. Line 8 is the line of the `match()`. Can anyone help me fix the problem? 
**It needs to be in awk because it is part of a large script.**

Comment: What specifically is the format of the string *in which the date resides*? And is the date always in parens, and is it always a capitalized three-character abbreviation for the month, and always a four digit year?

Comment: @aliteralmind No, sometimes it is in numerical form and even may be a range of time e.g. Dec, 12, 2013--Jan, 13, 2014. But it is always in parentheses and there will only be one pair of parentheses (this one) in the field.

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer this question without a lot more examples of potential input. It's good it's always in parentheses, but I'm assuming paretheses could also contain non-date text as well. What then?

Comment: @aliteralmind For the field $2, there will always be **one** pair of parentheses and inside it is always the date (which is what I want, though may in different formats, but I don't need to take care of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about grep? it was born to extract:

```
kent$ echo "the date is (Dec 2013)"|grep -Po '\(\K[^)]*'
Dec 2013
```

ok, you need awk:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{s="the date is (Dec 2013)";if(split(s,a,"[()]")==3)print a[2]}'
Dec 2013
```

above `s` would be your case `$2` and replace the `print` to a variable to do the assignment. I put entire thing in `BEGIN`, just for testing.

Comment: It needs to be in awk because it is part of a large script.

Comment: I only understand regex, out of all the technologies in this question. Can you explain why you reset the position with `\K`?

Comment: @aliteralmind, `\(\K` here is same as `(?<=()`, I used `\K` just for saving some typing. but after this comment, I realized, I failed.....

Comment: Well you taught me something, so you'll always be a success in my book.

Comment: @aliteralmind `\K` can handle un-fixed length, which is powerful and handy in some cases. However not all grep versions support it. I remembered there is explanation in wiki entry of `PCRE`, you can search for that, sorry for not posting the link.

Comment: I'll take a look. It's not something I've used before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub inside of AWK.  Basically this will chop the field down to what you want.

So you could do the following:

```
date = your_field
# this chops everything from front to first '('
sub("^.*\(", "", date) 

# this chops off everything from the last ')' to the end of the field
sub("\).*$", "", date)
```

[Awk String Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)